# What is the data type used for text properties?

Tags: text, properties, c++builder, vcl

I am porting over some code from a very old copy of Builder (> 15 years). In those days, the Text properties of various controls were of type `AnsiString`.  It appears that in the latest version of C++Builder, that is no longer the case. What is the data type?

All I can get from the help is `TCaption`, is that a type?

My code compiles and runs, but in trying to work with simple edit boxes, the text is not what is typed in, usually a '0'.  And `c_str()` works but gives the wrong value.

Comment: Looking further in help is the right thing to do for such simple matters. `Vcl.Controls.TCaption` clearly informs you: typedef System::UnicodeString TCaption;* and *TCaption is the type of the Caption property.* Now, try yourself, look up `System.UnicodeString.c_str`

Comment: For questions where the outcome is unexpected you need to provide a [mre]

Comment: Don't you mean AnsiString?

Answer (score 2):

The default string type used by C++Builder's RTL and VCL frameworks has always been whatever Delphi's native `String` type was at the time.  Things like `TCaption`, `TFileName`, etc were just aliases for `String` (but with distinct RTTI attached to them so the IDE's Object Inspector could differentiate between them).

Delphi's `String` type is a container for elements of Delphi's native `Char` type.

C++Builder provides `System::Char` and `System::String` aliases to match Delphi's native `Char` and `String` types:

- In C++Builder 2007 and earlier, Delphi's native `Char` type was `AnsiChar`, and so `System::Char` was an alias for C/C++'s `char`, and `System::String` was an alias for [`System::AnsiString`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.AnsiString).  Thus, `System::String` was an 8bit ANSI string, and `String::c_str()` returned a null-terminated `char*` pointer.
- In C++Builder 2009 and later, Delphi's native `Char` type is `WideChar`, and so `System::Char` is now an alias for `wchar_t` on Windows and `char16_t` on POSIX, and `System::String` is now an alias for [`System::UnicodeString`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.UnicodeString).  Thus, `System::String` is a 16bit UTF-16 string, and `String::c_str()` returns a null-terminated `wchar_t*`/`char16_t*` pointer, respectively.

So any code you have that operates on C-style string pointers, rather than using RTL features that operate on `System::String`, will have to be updated accordingly to move from ANSI to UTF-16.

See Embarcadero's [Unicode migration](https://www.embarcadero.com/rad-in-action/migration-upgrade-center#unicode) online resources.  The transition is *mostly* transparent for Delphi users, but for C++ users it tends to require a bit more work.

Comment: All great answers, thanks, looks like I have some research to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to migrate your code to Unicode.
At first get acquainted with next resources:

1. C++ Builder and Unicode
   https://community.embarcadero.com/index.php/blogs/entry/cbuilder-and-unicode-43342
2. Migrating your C++Builder Projects to Unicode:
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H-KFq5M0z0A&feature=emb_logo
3. Migration and Upgrade Center:
   https://www.embarcadero.com/rad-in-action/migration-upgrade-center

Good luck

Comment: Useful blog article by Al Mannarino: https://blogs.embarcadero.com/migrating-is-easier-than-you-think/

Answer (score 0):

**[DISCLAIMER]**
*All "code examples" are from the top of my head and not actually compiled.*

The `String` type is just a macro selecting the `AnsiString` or `UnicodeString` class depending on the `UNICODE` define.

Earlier, `UNICODE` was not defined by default so `char` was used, selecting the `AnsiString` class. Today `UNICODE` is defined by default so `wchar_t` is used, selecting the `UnicodeString` class. This is very convinient because Windows API are now by default Unicode.

There are several other types as `WideString`, `UTF8String` etc. They all have about the same interface (so they can be interchanged). Therefore `.c_str()` returns a different type depending on the selected `String` class.

To migrate you usually only have to put an `L` in front of all constant strings, such as `L"My unicode message"`

There should only be some rare cases where you specifically need an 8bit `char`. For these situations you can do a conversion with `AnsiString()`.

```
String Foo = "This is Unicode";

Bar(AnsiString(Foo).c_str()); // AnsiString converts Foo into an 8bit char pointer.
Baz(Foo.c_str());             // Foo returns a wchar_t pointer.
```

Windows API usually have two versions of each function, xxxxA for Ansi and xxxxW for the wide version. If you omit the ending `A` or `W`, Windows will use the right version depending on the `UNICODE` define. The W versions require you to use the `L"My string"` where A versions doesn't. Microsoft solved this with the `TEXT` macro: `TEXT("Auto converted")`. The `TEXT` macro will convert the constant string to either ansi or wide depending on the `UNICODE` define. This line will work correctly with both `UNICODE` defined or undefined by selecting the correct API function version.

```
MessageBox(TEXT("Auto converted string"),TEXT("TEXT MACRO"),0);
```

You can force Windows to use either the Ansi or Wide version by appending the A or W to the API function name.

```
MessageBoxA("This is the ansi version","MessageBoxA",0);
MessageBoxW(L"This is the wide version",L"MessageBoxW",0);
```

I would recommend you to migrate your project to only use `String` if possible and convert to `AnsiString` if it is absolutely required (such as calling a library function that only accepts 8bit `char`). `char` should be `wchar_t` by default in your project (see "project->Options->C++ Shared Options->_TCHAR maps to")